# Issue with SRT file on Handbrake

Tags: mp4, handbrake

I keep having this odd issue with Handbrake. Every time I burn in Captions, it skips the first one. So when I export the movie, all captions appear except the first one. I have seen others reporting this issue and no resolve.

So i am taking a SRT file and merging into an MP4 through handbrake. I tried changing the start time of the first caption, but this did not work.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible workaround, probably what you want because it's the most convenient :
add an extra empty "caption" at the beginning so it will skip this one.

Solution 2 : use another encoding GUI and prefer ass/ssa format instead of srt. Handbrake has always been limited in hardsubbing. Try Xvid4PSP, Shana Encoder, or Staxrip.

Comment: The blank caption worked... so annoying. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, sometimes we don't think about the simplest solution : )